# Unable to install dependencies for my project - husky git hooks

Tags: git, http-status-code-404, hook, husky

after recovering a project, dependencies don't want to install because of git hooks (husky)

I've tried several methods, such as deleting the package.json, installing the dependencies one by one or installing git hooks husky by hand, but to no avail. It's a template for working

> template-fullstack@3.0.0 postinstall
> cross-env-shell "husky install && cd ./frontend && $npm_package_config_cli install && cd ../backend && $npm_package_config_cli install"

husky - Git hooks installed
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fhelper-compilation-tcdets - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@babel/helper-compilation-tcdets@^7.20.7' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/max/.npm/_logs/2023-07-06T06_51_15_635Z-debug-0.log
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/max/Documents/Coding/Projects/2023-02-JS-Reims-project-3-origins-digital
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c cross-env-shell "husky install && cd ./frontend && $npm_package_config_cli install && cd ../backend && $npm_package_config_cli install"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/max/.npm/_logs/2023-07-06T06_51_14_675Z-debug-0.log

Comment: You question is not clearly explains the issue kindly update your question